# Why is git push not working on a former sub repository?

Tags: git, push, gitlab, pull

I have a project folder called `Project`. This is being tracked with git.
I have a subfolder called `SubProject`. This *was* being tracked with git, but I have since **deleted** the .git file inside of `SubProject`.

Now when I push to gitlab, gitlab still displays `SubProject` as it's own git repository. And when I pull down to another server, everything looks right except `SubProject` is just an empty folder.

What is going on?

Comment: You might need to 1) do a git submodule deinit SubProject, 2) check the .gitmodules file and manually remove the entries for SubProject, 3) git add the SubProject files. The issue is your main project still thinks SubProject is a submodule, even though you deleted the .git directory in SubProject.

Comment: When I clone it, I can't find any .gitmodule folder D:

Does .gitmodule survive pushes and pulls?

Is there any place where git would indicate "this project contains submodules" other than in a .gitmodules folder? 

p.s. currently googling this

Comment: So it's hard to tell what's going on, but yes, .gitmodules survives push / pulls and should be part of the main Project repo. If gitlab shows SubProject as a separate git repository, then it is registered as a submodule...you might be able to tell if you dig deep into the .git folder, but I'm not sure where you'd look. You might have initially tracked the SubProject folder as an empty folder before making it a git repository. If you want to add the files back, you should be able to do force-add the directory...